# Value from JSpinner not appearing when called (SWING)

Tags: java, swing, panel

i have a question regarding my jspinner, i figured out how to get the value by using the jspinner.getvalue(); method. but what i need to accomplish is the value from the spinner to be printed onto a panel that at the time is hidden, (it will be visible once the user presses on the "order" section of my program) here is the components of my code regarding my spinner, the button "add to order" which is supposed to add the variable from the jspinner to the textbox in the panel. then i will also show the code for my panel

spinner

```
int min = 0;
    int max = 9;
    int step = 1;
    int initValue = 0;
    SpinnerModel model = new SpinnerNumberModel(initValue, min, max, step);
    JSpinner a1 = new JSpinner(model);
    a1.setBounds(6, 200, 33, 26);
    contentPane.add(a1);
    JFormattedTextField tf = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) a1.getEditor()).getTextField();
    tf.setEditable(false);
    tf.setBackground(Color.white);
```

the add to order button which is supposed to print the variable from the spinner to the panel

```
    JButton btnAddToOrder = new JButton("Add To Order");
    btnAddToOrder.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
```

and finally my panel

```
orderDeet = new JTextField((Integer) a1.getValue());
    orderDeet.setEditable(true);
    orderDeet.setBounds(20, 33, 296, 235);
    panel.add(orderDeet);
    orderDeet.setColumns(10);
```

i can also show the code for the button to make the panel visible if needed but i dont want to make the question too complicated.

Comment: `new JTextField((Integer) a1.getValue());` probably does not do what you think it does.  See [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#JTextField-int-).

Comment: would i have to change the integer to a string? is there anyway you could help me @VGR

Comment: Yes, JTextFields can only display String values.  Read the link.  Look at the various constructors for JTextField (there are five of them).

Comment: when i change it to a string my program just seems to crash, im lost

Comment: If you got an exception, read it;  it’s telling you exactly what went wrong, why, and where.

Comment: nevermind! i got it to work. i used orderDeet.setText("" + a1.getValue());

whats wrong though is it only prints out 0, do you know of something i can add to my textbox which lets it actively change text?

Comment: corretion! i got it to work, i just made the textbox set text from the jspinner once the button was clicked1

Comment: could i also ask another question, how can i make it so when something else is added to the order screen, it starts on a new line instead of replacing  the other previous number, would i use the \n method @VGR

Comment: I would suggest asking a new question with your new issue.  Remember to include the code that’s causing the problem, and remember to describe both the behavior you want to see and the behavior you’re seeing instead.

Comment: i figured everything out myself, i will though thank you